# NSSortDescriptor sorting with part of key possible?

Tags: iphone, ios, sorting, core-data, nssortdescriptor

I have a CoreData iphone application with a view that display addresses.

An address looks like this: "5 Blob Street, 2222, Suburbia", where "5 Blob Street" is the address_and_number key, "2222" the post code, and "Suburbia" the suburb.

Currently I use this NSSortDescriptor, which works fine:

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] 
                                    initWithKey:@"address_and_number" ascending:YES];
```

However, my client wants to sort by street name, i.e. out of the address_and_number key, "Blob Street" would be evaluated.

Is there any way to do such sorting without resorting to splitting the address_and_number key into two keys, "address" and "number"?

Can I use perhaps a regular expression to grab only the part of the address_and_number key I need for sorting, and somehow add that to the NSSortDescriptor object?

Comment: Perhaps an NSComparator would be of use?

Comment: Perhaps this is relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3455512/custom-sorting-using-categories-and-core-data-is-it-supported-by-the-framework

Answer (score 1):

According to the answer at a relevant question at [Custom sorting using categories and core data - is it supported by the framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3455512/custom-sorting-using-categories-and-core-data-is-it-supported-by-the-framework)

> Sorting inside of the NSFetchedResultsController is performed at the persistent store level so if you are using SQLite as the backend it will fail.
>
> For something like this I would de-normalize the data and store the month and day of month in addition to the actual birthdate so that you can sort on them.

After trying both a selector and a comparator, none of which worked as my persistent level I am using sqlite3, I resorted to splitting the address_and_number key into  address_street_name and address_street_number keys, and then sorting by address_street_name.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a NSComparator block to the initialization of the NSSortDescriptor like this:

```
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]
                                    initWithKey:@"Address_suburb" ascending:YES comparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
                                      // do your comparison without house numbers here
                                      // return either NSOrderedAscending, NSOrderedDescending or NSOrderedSame
                                    }];
```

Comment: This doesn't work apparently when persistence layer is sqlite3. Which is true in my case.