# Using CoreData how to configure a fetch request to find upcoming birthdays?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nspredicate, nsfetchrequest

I’m using Xcode 7.3 and Swift 2.2 with an `NSFetchedResultsController`. Is it possible to create the required fetch request configured with a predicate and sort descriptors to solve this problem?

Given a `Person` entity that has a `birthDate` attribute how do I configure a fetch request to return upcoming birthdays? Here’s what I have tried:

1. I created a transient attribute called `birthDateThisYear` and configured it to return the person’s birthday this year. But I discovered that you can’t use a transient attribute in a fetch request with Core Data.
2. I tried the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3455512/custom-sorting-using-categories-and-core-data-is-it-supported-by-the-framework) by denormalizing with `birthDateDayNumber` and `birthDateMonthNumber` attributes along with a custom setter for `birthDate` but I couldn’t figure out the predicate. What if today was Dec 31? Somehow it would need to wrap around to include Jan, Feb, and Mar.
3. I read that it could be done with expressions and comparison predicates. But I couldn’t figure out a solution. Anyone got this working?
4. I thought it work to create a denormalized attribute called `birthDateInYear2000` but, again, that suffers from the same overlap problem.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suggestion:

- Fetch **all** birthdays.
- Map the birthdays to the next occurrence from now

  ```
  let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
  let nextBirthDays = birthdays.map { (date) -> NSDate in
    let components = calendar.components([.Day, .Month], fromDate: date)
    return calendar.nextDateAfterDate(NSDate(), matchingComponents: components, options: .MatchNextTime)!
  }
  ```
- Sort the dates

  ```
  let sortedNextBirthDays = nextBirthDays.sort { $0.compare($1) == .OrderedAscending }
  ```
- Now `sortedNextBirthDays` contains all upcoming birthdays sorted ascending.

In Core Data you could fetch records as dictionary with birthday and objectID (or full name), create a temporary struct, map and sort the items and get the person for the objectID (or use the full name) – or you even could apply the logic to an  `NSManagedObject` array

**Edit**

Using an `NSFetchedResultsController` you can sort the table view **only** if the information about the next birthday is stored in the persistent store (assuming it's the MySQL-store), because you can't apply sort descriptors including keys pointing to transient or computed properties.

The best place to update the `nextBirthDate` property is just before creating the `NSFetchedResultsController` instance of the view controller.

- Create an (optional) attribute `nextBirthDate` in the entity `Person`
- Create a extension of `NSDate` to calculate the next occurrence of a date from now

  ```
  extension NSDate {
    var nextOccurrence : NSDate {
      let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
      let components = calendar.components([.Day, .Month], fromDate: self)
      return calendar.nextDateAfterDate(NSDate(), matchingComponents: components, options: .MatchNextTime)!
    }
  }
  ```
- In the closure to initialize the `NSFetchResultsController` instance add code to update the `nextBirthDate` property of each record

  ```
  lazy var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController = {
     let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Person")
     do {
        let people = try self.managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest) as! [Person]
        people.forEach({ (person) in
          let nextBirthDate = person.birthDate.nextOccurrence
          if person.nextBirthDate == nil || person.nextBirthDate! != nextBirthDate {
             person.nextBirthDate = nextBirthDate
          }
        })
        if self.managedObjectContext.hasChanges {
           try self.managedObjectContext.save()
        }
     } catch {
       print(error)
     }

     // Set the batch size to a suitable number.
     fetchRequest.fetchBatchSize = 20
     // Edit the sort key as appropriate.
     let sortDescriptors =  [NSSortDescriptor(key:"nextBirthDate", ascending: true)]
     fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = sortDescriptors
     ...
  ```
- If the view controller can edit the `birthDate` property don't forget to update the `nextBirthDate` property as well to keep the view in sync.

Comment: Looks promising! I neglected to say that I'm using a `NSFetchedResultsController`. Do you think your answer could be adapted to that? It doesn't seem so. It needs to be handed a configured `NSFetchRequest`.

Comment: I updated the answer suggesting a solution with `NSFetchedResultsController`. The only disadvantage is that the `nextBirthDate` property must be persistent.

Comment: Good thinking! I'll try it. And this may not work well for large data sets but this app will have a low number of Person entities. Probably no more than 25 ever.

Comment: I don't think there is a performance issue. The `nextBirthDate` properties are changed only on the first run and if the new value is not the same as the saved. Anyway there is always only one fetch and one save task from and to the database. Basically consider to store the birth dates on noon rather than midnight to avoid potential daylight saving changes issues. By the way: birthdays on Feb 29 in leap years are calculated as Mar 1 in non-leap years. To get Feb 28 change `.MatchNextTime` into `.MatchPreviousTimePreservingSmallerUnits` in the `NSDate` extension.

Comment: With some small changes for my situation this works like a charm. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

my suggestion is similar:

- fetch all customers/persons
- filter all birthdates that range 3 days before and 3 days after today

Use closure like the following:

```
func fetchBirthdayList(){
    // this example considers all birthdays that are like
    // |---TODAY---|
    // Each hyphen represents a day
    let date = Date()
    let timeSpan = 3
    let cal = Calendar.current
    nextBirthDays = self.list.filter { (customer) -> Bool in
        if let birthDate = customer.birthDate {
            let difference = cal.dateComponents([.day,.year], from: birthDate as! Date, to: date)
            return (( (difference.day! <= timeSpan) || ((365 - difference.day!) <= timeSpan) ) && difference.day! >= 0)
        }
        return false
    }
}
```

If you want, you can order the result afterwards.

Cheers

Oliver